# Show that the topology of finite complements is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the topology of finite complements is not Hausdorff.

I've found some previous questions on this subject, but I do not find a clear answer.

First, the definitions:

> Let $X$ be a set, then the topology of finite complements is defined as:
> $$\tau = \{ V\subseteq X: X\setminus V \text{ is finite}\} \cup \{ \varnothing\}$$
>
> Hausdorff:
>
> $$(\forall x,y\in X, x\not = y)(\exists U,V\in \tau)(x\in U \wedge y\in V\wedge U\cap V = \varnothing)$$

So I want to show that there are two different pionts $x,y\in (X,\tau)$ that cannot be *seperated*. Or $(\forall U, V\in \tau)(U\cap V \not = \varnothing)$ if $x\in U, y\in V$.

I've tried different approaches but I don't seem to get there, how about this try:

Assume $(X,\tau)$ to be Hausdorff, then for a random $x,y\in X$ we find $U,V\in \tau$ such that $U\cap V = \varnothing$.

Now I try to find a contradiction:
Since $U, V \in \tau$, then $X\setminus U, X\setminus V$ are finite. This means $(X\setminus U)\cup(X\setminus V) = X\setminus (U\cap V)$ is finite. Which means $U\cap V \in \tau$.

And then I'm thinking: *so what?*.

I feel like there is some contradiction to be found using this kind of approach, but how do I get there?

Comment: It *is* Hausdorff if $X$ is finite; you need to add the assumption that $X$ is an infinite set. Then just show that any two non-empty open sets have non-empty intersection.

Comment: Okay, that seems fair. Then $X\setminus (U\cap V)$ is finite which results in $U\cap V$ being non-empty which leads to a contradiction. And to prove the finite case, then let $U=\{x\} \in \tau$ and $V=\{y\}\in \tau$ where $U\cap V = \varnothing$?

Comment: Yes: if $X$ is finite, this is simply the discrete topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You're almost there. Suppose that $X$ is infinite. If $(X,\tau)$ is Hausdorff, take $x,y \in X$, $x \neq y$, and open sets $U \ni x$, $V \ni y$ with $U \cap V = \varnothing.$ Since $U$ and $V$ are non-empty, $X \setminus U$ and $X \setminus V$ are both finite, ok. But the catch is $U \cap V = \varnothing \implies U \subset X \setminus V$, and so $U$ is finite. Moral of the history: $$X = U \cup (X \setminus U),$$ with the union disjoint. Now I ask you: *so what*?